# Unity: звонок по номеру телефона с игры по нажатию кнопки

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в интерфейсе открывалось приложение Телефон с набранным номером.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй:

```
public Update()
{
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 18 * 13, Screen.height / 14 * 13, 75, 25), "112")) { 
        Intent outVar = new Intent();
        outVar.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        outVar.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("+12345#123")));
        startActivity(outVar);
    };
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но помогите теперь это запихать в кнопку.

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 18 * 13,
            Screen.height / 14 * 13, 75, 25), "112"))
        {
        }

Comment: Нет, не работает, требует ; и } в кнопке

Comment: так поставь :) Я пишу тебе код из головы не проверяя в компиляторе. Т.ч. могу допускать некие синтаксические ошибки :)

Comment: Разобрался, не стоило обзывать "out" а так всё ок